# Display Excel Table in Dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, css, excel

Can someone help me with this? I have a table in Excel with a lot of data and I want to display this data in dropdown menu in my website. Here's more specific:

```
Table:
| ROW1 | Data | Data | Data | RESULT | RESULT |
| ROW2 | Data | Data | Data | RESULT | RESULT |
```

Now, I need to choose from 4 different drop downs on my website and than show the result from the last 2 columns of the table. How can I achive this?

The website is developed with HTML, CSS, JS/jQuery, so if it's possible I want to use this languages. If not, I'll implement another one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do the job with your desired languages. Following link can be usable.

[How can I pass local Excel file data to Javascript array (for google charts)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24526141/how-can-i-pass-local-excel-file-data-to-javascript-array-for-google-charts)